# How to include spaces in batch variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I run the following batch script which asks the user for information and assigns this to the variables.

```
set var_type=1
set var_name=1
set var_technology=1

set /p var_type="Enter type (E.g. "Equipment" or "Technology"): "
IF /I %var_type%==Technology set /p var_technology="Enter technology name: "
set /p var_name="Enter name: "

cmd /k python "script.py" %var_type% %var_technology% %var_name%
```

The script works fine when the user types in a single string. E.g:

```
Enter type (E.g. "Equipment" or "Technology"): Technology
Enter technology name: Solar
Enter name: Philips
```

The above variables are passed to a python script which creates folders using the names above:

```
C:/Users/ME/Desktop/Technology/Solar/Philips
```

But if the user types in a second string for the `technology name`, the second string is treated as the third variable. E.g:

```
Enter type (E.g. "Equipment" or "Technology"): Technology
Enter technology name: Solar PV
Enter name: Philips
```

Now the folder structure is:

```
C:/Users/ME/Desktop/Technology/Solar/PV
```

Where it should be:

```
C:/Users/ME/Desktop/Technology/Solar PV/Philips
```

---

Instead of forcing users to use an underscore between strings, is there a method to include spaces in the variables?

Comment: Change `IF /I %var_type%==Technology` to `IF /I "%var_type%"=="Technology"` to avoid trouble in case `%var_type%` value contains spaces...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote your arguments:

```
cmd /k python "script.py" "%var_type%" "%var_technology%" "%var_name%"
```

As an aside: Any reason why you're starting a new shell there? And keep it open afterwards (`/k`)? And why the `echo on` at the end?

Comment: Wow, that simple...many thanks for your answer ;). The python script prints some messages to the shell hence why I would like to keep it open with `/k`. But I think you're right about `@echo on`.

Comment: Well, in your case you're starting a *new* shell which is never closed just to keep things open. Why not just add `pause` at the end?